# postgresql condition to only apply on one column in the select

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.1

I have a query as follows

```
select
    cheque_no,
    sum(credit),
    date
from ac_cash_collection
group by 1,3;
```

now I want `sum(credit)` from records whose `transaction_type ilike banking`, but this condition should not apply on other columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `case` statement inside the `sum()`, like this:

```
select
    cheque_no,
    sum(case when transaction_type like `%banking%` then credit else 0 end),
    date
from ac_cash_collection
group by 1,3
```